# A simple login script sometimes work and sometimes doesn't

Tags: userscripts

I have the following code I execute in Chrome with Tampermonkey, which I use to login to [digitalocean.com](https://digitalocean.com).

```
setTimeout (function() {
document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").click();
}, 3000);
```

For some reason, this code sometimes work and sometimes it doesn't: That is, sometimes I'm logged in and sometimes (most cases) I get DigitalOcean's **404** webpage.

My login details are already saved in local storage and appear on the form.

By principle, this problem can be reproduced by registering to DigitalOcean, installing Tampermonkey, and executing the code with it, with the match:

```
https://cloud.digitalocean.com/login*
```

Might something be missing to ensure human-like behavior in the eyes of the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it took some digging, but I see what's going on.

- There is an authentication token in the form.
- If the token is not what the server expects, it kicks you to a `404` error at `https://cloud.digitalocean.com/sessions`.
- If your browser loads the login page from cache (usually because you got to it by clicking the "back" button in your browser) you'll be submitting an invalid token (the one you got back when the page was put in the cache).
- Sometimes it's wrong for some other reason I haven't figured out.

## To deal with the cache-loaded page issue

I'd edit your script check if the page was loaded from cache, and refresh the page instead of triggering the `click` event:

```
if (window.performance.navigation.type === 2)
{
    location.reload();
} else {
    document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").click();
}
```

## The other issue is probably an issue with DigitalOcean's back-end

I'd recommend that you report the fact that their login page seems to occasionally get a bad authentication token, as the issue can intermittently be reproduced by clicking (with the mouse) on the "Log In" button of a freshly loaded copy of the page.
(I wouldn't mention the script or they'll blame it and then you'll be out of luck.)

### In the mean-time

As a stop-gap until they fix their issue, you could make a new script matching `https://cloud.digitalocean.com/sessions` (it sends me to that page exactly, but add a `*` if it's needed) that sends you back if you came from the login page, and got a `404` error:

```
if (document.referrer.startsWith("https://cloud.digitalocean.com/login") && document.title.endsWith(" (404)"))
{
    history.back();
}
```

Note that `document.title.endsWith(" (404)")` only works because the contents of their `404` page's `<title>` tag ends with `(404)`.

Comment: Upon looking back at this again, it looks like DigitalOcean has fixed the issue that was causing the authentication token to be wrong sometimes, but they throttle you if you make too many requests too quickly, sending you again to https://cloud.digitalocean.com/sessions, but this time with a HTTP status code of "200" (OK), and "Ooops! Your request has been throttled." as the title. If you're running into this new error, you *may* be able to rewrite the script(s) to accommodate this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in Tampermonkey as the reported behavior doesn't happen in Greasemonkey.

Anyway, 3D1T0R's answer provides an interesting workaround with the current situation (would thumb up if I could).

Comment: It's not tampermonkey. I'm able to reproduce by clicking (yes, with my mouse) the "Log In" button even if neither tampermonkey or greasemonkey are installed.

Comment: wow! Are you a DigitalOcean customer? What browser do you use?

Comment: @3D1T0R I marked your your answer as correct but a follow up could help.

Comment: No, I'm not a DigitalOcean customer, and I used both Firefox and Chrome.
I just saw your question and was able to reproduce it, so I examined it.